# How to pull a particular tag code changes from bitbucket?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have 2 commits to master branch which are tagged, v.1.1 and v.1.2.How can I pull only v.1.2?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you are trying to do? "Pull" in git normally refers to the "git pull" command, which wouldn't normally be used with tags. And "only" implies that you want v1.1 to be excluded from something, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just pull a tag you first need to fetch the entire branch and then checkout the specific tag you want into a separate branch.
e.g:

```sh
git pull origin master --tags
```

then checkout the tag v.1.2 into a branch, lets call it v.1.2-branch

```sh
git checkout tags/v.1.2 -b v.1.2-branch
```